# Get environment in an intern unit test suite

Tags: unit-testing, intern

I'm running some unit tests in multiple environments. I'm trying to write a unit test for some platform dependant code, so I need a way to know which environment I'm running. I've figured out how to do it in a functional test (using `this.remote`) but not a unit test.

Is there a way I can identify the running environment from the inside of a unit test suite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are writing a unit test for a browser then you can find out what browser they are running in through the [`navigator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator) global object, but—and this is true for all code, including tests—you should use [feature detection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh273397%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), **not** UA/environment sniffing, to determine whether or not certain functionality is available.

Comment: The platform specific code I have is working around a buggy feature of Firefox, so feature detection couldn't help me. I wanted to avoid using the user agent or the navigator in the tests, because that's what the tested code is already doing. If intern can give me which browser is running, i'll be testing the platform detection as well. 

Does that mean I'll have to write a functional test instead?

Comment: What is the buggy feature?

Comment: svg `<use>` tag is randomly rendering or not on firefox, so when firefox is detected on the user agent, my code is inlining the SVG symbol instead of referencing it with a `<use>` tag

Comment: Yikes. If it’s truly random, then testing the user-agent from the browser is the way to go. When you’re just running unit tests directly in a browser there is no Intern runner behind it to tell you what browser you’re running in; the browser itself tells you. (Also I hope you [reported the bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org).)